# Why do the Manley-Rowe relations use this Hamiltonian and how can I derive it?

Tags: plasma-physics, non-linear-systems, non-linear-optics

The derivation of the Manley-Rowe relations begin with the following Hamiltonian for 3 classical, coupled harmonic oscillators:

$H=(p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2)/2m+1/2(k_1q_1^2+k_2q_2^2+k_3q_3^2)+\lambda q_1q_2q_3$

where the $p$'s are (presumably) the oscillator momenta, and the $q$'s are (presumably) their positions. The k's and $\lambda$ are constants.

This Hamiltonian is the starting point for deriving the Manley-Rowe relations as used to describe parametric instabilities induced by EM waves travelling through non-linear media, and I'm trying to understand where it comes from. I'm mostly interesting in understanding the application of the Manley-Rowe relations to Stimulated Raman Scattering.
How can I derive this Hamiltonian from first principles (in the context of eventually deriving the Manley-Rowe relations for Stimulated Raman Scattering)?

Comment: Presumably you're starting from a diagram of the system, right? We have to know what the physical system looks like in order to use first principles.

Comment: I want to understand where the Manley-Rowe relations come from, and this Hamiltonian is the starting point often quoted in textbooks, with no diagram given. I've edited the question to mention this.

Comment: There are many ways to couple harmonic oscillators, and the term $\lambda q_1 q_2 q_3$ is just one of them. Presumably, it's a useful choice for whatever problem the Manley-Rowe relations are used for, but it's not clear from the question what that is.

Comment: @knzhou Presumably it is, and I want to know why. If I delete the question and change the title to "Why do the Manley-Rowe relations use this Hamiltonian and how can I derive it?" would that be better?

Comment: Yeah, that's much better, you can just change the title of this question as it is! You're also more likely to get a useful answer if you add more detail about what system the Manley-Rowe relations are used for.